# Console Application: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, rider

I have a .NET console application (.NETFramework v.4.8) that reads a CSV file in the root of my project.

```cs
File.ReadAllLines("fuel.csv");
```

[image: Screenshot of Cars project]

When I run my program, I get the following error:

```sh
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 
"/Users/ryan.payne/Sites/linq-fundamentals/LinqFundamentals/Cars/bin/Debug/fuel.csv"
```

How do I get my console application to read the file?

Comment: All right, but did you follow, in the first link, how they manage to read that file once it is embedded?

Comment: @Steve I realized that those directions are for a Xamarin app and not for a console application. I clarified that part of my question. I've resolved the issue and posted my findings in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65332151/11809808.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

#### Option 1 - Manually edit `.csproj` file

Open the `.csproj` file and replace `<None Include="fuel.csv">` with the following:

```xml
<None Include="fuel.csv">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
```

#### Option 2 - Update properties in dialog

1. Right click on the file
2. Click "Properties"
3. Set "Copy to output directory" to "Copy if newer" (scroll down if you don't see these options)

[image]

Comment: Alternatively you can read from resource when you decide to embed it as resource, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140/how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file

Comment: Not sure about Rider, but in Visual Studio you can select the file in the solution explorer tree and then set the property 'Copy To Output Directory' there, no need to open the .csproj file. I'm guessing Rider may have the same ability.

Comment: @quaabaam Unfortunately, that feature is not available in Rider. ☹️

Comment: @quaabaam Turns out the feature is available in Rider. I missed the scrollbar and didn't realize there were more options. I've updated my answer accordingly.